# Is it possible to do a outer apply on two tables from different database engines to get unmatched records?

Tags: sql-server, left-join, outer-apply, database-engine

I am trying to find records that are in table C but not in table M in a column called records. I am doing an outer apply but the query does not finish executing. It does not give any errors. The two tables are in different database engines. I am confident that I am doing it correctly because I can do a left outer join - it is not giving me the results I want hence trying an outer apply. Below is my query.

```sql
SELECT M.records, C.records,
    CASE WHEN M.records = C.records
        THEN '1'
        ELSE '0'
    END
    AS RESULT
FROM [DB_1].[dbo].[Records_Overview] M
OUTER APPLY [DB_2].[dbo].[Records_Individual] C
WHERE M.record_Type = 'individual'
```

If anyone has another way of solving this please add. I am open to trying different methods.
Just to reiterate, I am trying to find records that are in the column records of table M but not in the column records of table C.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Below is my desired results.

| M.records | C.records | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 123 | 1 |
| 122 | NULL | 0 |
| 321 | 321 | 1 |
| NULL | 332 | 0 |
| 768 | 567 | 0 |
| 454 | 454 | 1 |
| 790 | NULL | 0 |
| NULL | 209 | 0 |

Comment: You mean database, not engine? Your syntax does not indicate using different engine - the latest would be using oracle server through SQL linked server for example. Why not to use `left join on M.records = C.records`? Currently you are creating cartesian product (multiplying all records between tables) and this is very slow approach.

Comment: Re "I am confident that I am doing it correctly" - why you are asking here then? :)

Comment: @Arvo you are right it is different databases, not different engines sorry for that. I am asking on here to find a more optimized way of doing this. Queries should not be executing for 20 minutes plus with no output. Also, I am not getting errors, that's why I am pretty sure my query is not wrong.

Comment: But your quey is not optimal. If you need to get null values from both tables, then you have to use full outer join; if you need to set filters for either table, then you cannot set them in where clause - this excludes null values easily. You can use join between filtered subqueries however. Cross join or apply without conditions just multiplies tables and takes huge amount of time and resources.